# no method getEditor() error when combining CellEditing with checkbox selection model on ExtJS 4.0 GridPanel

Tags: extjs4

im using extjs 4.0 and am trying to combine an editable grid with a checkbox selection model.
Problem is when i click on the checkbox i get this error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getEditor'
```

its clear to me that the checkbox column isn´t supposed to be edited (in the cellediting plugin way) so there's no getEditor function.

i tried defining a beforeedit listener on CellEditing component that skips edition for colIdx = 0 but it doesn´t even get called because the error occurs just before this happens, on the startEditByClick method.

So, my question is, should I:

a) define a getEditor NO-OP function and bind it to the first column? i don´t know if this is even possible

b) define a listener to skip edition when colIdx = 0 that fires before the startEditByClick function gets called? on what event of what component would this be?

c) ignore javascript errors as long as it works (:P)

here´s some code

```js
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 1
});

Ext.define('RPV.view.aviso.AvisosList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    store: 'AvisosStore',

    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel'),
    plugins: [cellEditing],

    initComponent: function () {
        this.columns = [{
            header: 'NIV',
            dataIndex: 'niv',
            flex: 1,
            editable: false
        }, {
            header: 'NCI',
            dataIndex: 'nci',
            flex: 1,
            editable: false
        }, {
            header: 'Tipo movimiento',
            dataIndex: 'tipoMovimiento',
            width: 130,
            field: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                typeAhead: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                selectOnTab: true,
                store: 'TipoMovimientoStore',
                lazyRender: true,
                listClass: 'x-combo-list-small',
                mode: 'remote',
                minChars: 0,
                valueField: 'descripcion',
                displayField: 'descripcion',
                emptyText: 'No especificado'
            }
        }, {
            header: 'Observaciones',
            dataIndex: 'observacionesDwr',
            width: 130,
            field: {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                typeAhead: true,
                triggerAction: 'all',
                selectOnTab: true,
                store: 'ObservacionesStore',
                lazyRender: true,
                mode: 'remote',
                minChars: 0,
                valueField: 'descripcion',
                displayField: 'descripcion',
                autoSelect: false
            }
        }];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

UPDATE: found this link http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137731-Using-checkbox-selection-model-in-the-editable-grid-produces-an-error&highlight=CellEditing
that says this is a bug, thats already been fixed for version 4.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
onBeforeEditCell : function(event) {        
        if (event.column && event.column.isCheckerHd) {
            return false;
        } 

        return true;
    }
```

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?140253-Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing-Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-TypeError

Comment: i solved it with `var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
 clicksToEdit: 1,
 beforeEdit : function(event) {        
        if (event.column && event.column.isCheckerHd) {
            return false;
        } 

        return true;
    }
});` but still am going to accept answer cuz it was really helpful and pointed me in the right direction